# Java - threads + action

Tags: java

I'm new to Java so I have a simple question that I don't know where to start from - 
I need to write a function that accepts an Action, at a multi-threads program , and only the first thread that enter the function do the action, and all the other threads wait for him to finish, and then return from the function without doing anything.

As I said - I don't know where to begin because, 
first -  there isn't a static var at the function (static like as in c / c++ ) so how do I make it that only the first thread would start the action, and the others do nothing ?
second - for the threads to wait, should I use

```
public synchronized void lala(Action doThis)
{....}
```

or should i write something like that inside the function

```
synchronized (this)
{
...
notify();
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Is this homework? Anyway, you shouldn't automatically think "oh, I need threads!". Approach it from the viewpoint of solving the problem.

Comment: Not homework, already finished my degree :) but don't know Java so I'm trying to write something..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all threads arriving at a method to wait for the first, then they must synchronize on a common object. It could be the same instance (this) on which the methods are invoked, or it could be any other object (an explicit lock object).

If you want to ensure that the first thread is the only one that will perform the action, then you must store this fact somewhere, for all other threads to read, for they will execute the same instructions.

Going by the previous two points, one could lock on this 'fact' variable to achieve the desired outcome

```
static final AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean(false); // synchronize on this, and also store the fact. It is static so that if this is in a Runnable instance will not appear to reset the fact. Don't use the Boolean wrapper, for the value of the flag might be different in certain cases.

public void lala(Action doThis)
{
    synchronized (flag) // synchronize on the flag so that other threads arriving here, will be forced to wait
    {
        if(!flag.get()) // This condition is true only for the first thread.
        {
           doX();
           flag.set(true); //set the flag so that other threads will not invoke doX.
        }
    }
    ...
    doCommonWork();
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Roee84, you're welcome. There are a few things that I would like to add. 1.) If you know that classes could be loaded multiple times in a JVM, using multiple classloaders, then the above approach will have to be modified to use a flag that is unique to the JVM. 2.) You might make this less complex if you use a Latch (the flag will have to be used, but you do not need to synchronize on it). 3.) If you want to learn concurrency for Java in detail, get a copy of Java Concurrency in Practice.

Comment: -1.  Don't synchronize on `Boolean.FALSE`, it's a singleton and globally accessible, which is asking for trouble.  Also, the flag value is static and mutable, which is asking for trouble as well.  The question doesn't imply whether this caching behavior should be at the static (class) level or at the instance level, and it's safer to avoid `static` until you know you need it.

Comment: But +1 to your comment recommending Java Concurrency in Practice, which is indeed an excellent reference.

Comment: Damn, I need coffee. Staying late and working on concurrency doesnt help my rep.

Comment: @Daniel, I suppose I could get that rep back ;-) Edit: Please!!

Comment: LOL :) As I said , I'm new to Java so thank you very much. Hope I'll get better at this soon... :-)

Comment: @Vineet: I've removed my downvote, but I'm still a bit dubious about using both an `AtomicBoolean` **and** a `synchronized` block.  You should be safe to just use a `volatile boolean` and `synchronized(this)`, or alternatively you can construct a private final object intended to be used only as a lock if you're paranoid about other people locking on your object.

Comment: @Roee84: Well, I wish I had better news, but the truth is, concurrency is **hard**.  It is **very** easy to get it wrong, and especially to get it wrong in ways that work well enough 99% of the time and then fail catastrophically in that other 1%.  I think my advice to you would be to avoid threading as much as possible until you understand it well enough to know why you want to avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: @Daniel, AtomicBoolean is safe to synchronize on. It has a constructor that creates a new object to synchronize on; which was not the case with the `Boolean` wrapper class as you pointed out. In other words, it's equivalent to extending `Object`, but having a value attribute to store the boolean value. Your second point of using a `volatile boolean` and the `this` object to synchronize on, is valid. It's just that I didn't want to have an explicit lock, and a flag at the same time.

Comment: @Vineet: Sorry for the misunderstanding -- I think we're both trying to say the same thing.  I agree, `AtomicBoolean` is safe to synchronize on, and your answer looks thread-safe to me, so I've removed my downvote (and even added an upvote!).  You do add a small bit of unnecessary overhead by using `AtomicBoolean.set()` where an ordinary `volatile` store would have been sufficient, and that's all I was trying to point out.

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing threading in any recent version of Java, you really should be using the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package instead of using `Thread`s directly.

Here's one way you could do it:

```
private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
private final Map<Runnable, Future<?>> submitted 
    = new HashMap<Runnable, Future<?>>();

public void executeOnlyOnce(Runnable action) {
    Future<?> future = null;
    // NOTE: I was tempted to use a ConcurrentHashMap here, but we don't want to
    // get into a possible race with two threads both seeing that a value hasn't
    // been computed yet and both starting a computation, so the synchronized
    // block ensures that no other thread can be submitting the runnable to the
    // executor while we are checking the map.  If, on the other hand, it's not
    // a problem for two threads to both create the same value (that is, this
    // behavior is only intended for caching performance, not for correctness),
    // then it should be safe to use a ConcurrentHashMap and use its
    // putIfAbsent() method instead.
    synchronized(submitted) {
        future = submitted.get(action);
        if(future == null) {
            future = executor.submit(action);
            submitted.put(action, future);
        }
    }
    future.get(); // ignore return value because the runnable returns void
}
```

Note that this assumes that your `Action` class (I'm assuming you don't mean [`javax.swing.Action`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html), right?) implements `Runnable` and also has a reasonable implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()`.  Otherwise, you may need to use a different `Map` implementation (for example, `IdentityHashMap`).

Also, this assumes that you may have multiple different actions that you want to execute only once.  If that's not the case, then you can drop the Map entirely and do something like this:

```
private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
private final Object lock = new Object();
private volatile Runnable action;
private volatile Future<?> future = null;

public void executeOnlyOnce(Runnable action) {
    synchronized(lock) {
        if(this.action == null) {
            this.action = action;
            this.future = executor.submit(action);
        } else if(!this.action.equals(action)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected action");
        }
    }
    future.get();
}
```

Comment: thank you very much , I'm kind of new to Java so I don't familiar yet with all this, but it's look like a great answer so thank you ! :)

Comment: and thanks for the editing as well :) I'm saving this for future use :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public synchronized void foo()
{
 ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
public void foo()
{
     synchronized(this)
     {
          ... 
     }
}
```

so either of the two options should work. I personally like the synchronized method option.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronizing the whole method can sometimes be overkill if there is only a certain part of the code that deals with shared data (for example, a common variable that each thread is updating).

Best approach for performance is to only use the synchronized keyword just around the shared data. If you synchronized the whole method when it is not entirely necessarily then a lot of threads will be waiting when they can still do work within their own local scope.

When a thread enters the synchronize it acquires a lock (if you use the *this* object it locks on the object itself), the other will wait till the lock-acquiring thread has exited. You actually don't need a *notify* statement in this situation as the threads will release the lock when they exit the synchronize statement.